# I just shifted my databases to a sql server 2008 cluster connected to a SAN and its started giving me the following errors

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008, san

SQL Server has encountered 1 occurrence(s) of I/O requests taking longer than 15 seconds to complete on file [T:\MSSQL\DATA\%file_name%] in database [%DB_name%] (2).  The OS file handle is 0×00000838.  The offset of the latest long I/O is: 0×000000ebdc0000

Has anyone encountered and solved this?

Comment: you might want to try on serverfault also

Answer (score 2):

Please see this - you may have IO issues - and physical drive issues

http://blogs.msdn.com/chrissk/archive/2008/06/19/i-o-requests-taking-longer-than-15-seconds-to-complete-on-file.aspx